# TypeScript type for onClick event considering it could be triggered from the keyboard?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The React Typescript cheatsheet here recommends typing a click event like so:

https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet#basic-prop-types-examples

```
onClick(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void;
```

However it's possible to trigger a button or link via the keyboard, and the `onClick` event will still fire. Does that mean this typing is technically wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes "technically" its wrong but, the common case is that a click is done with a mouse, but then it can also be done with a track pad or your finger.

TypeScript is a compile time feature, so generally the technical incorrectness of the type here really does not matter to the browser or end user as long as you are still getting the benefits of the typing.

Although you can always just rename it by assigning it to a new type but that would not be a good idea as it might throw off other devs.